# What is the difference between Qt event handler and boost ASIO's io_service?

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, boost, asio

Both are asynchronous event handlers with an event loop. That's the head line.

In Qt an event loop starts with `QApplication::exec()`, and with io_service starts with `io_service::run()`. My question is after this point. **What are the things that I can achieve in Qt and not in io_service and vice-versa? What are the limitations? When is either preferable (ignoring Qt's GUI)?**

**More unimportant info: What triggered this question in my mind** is that I was testing some C++ Qt-based program, where I have the logic of my GUI in a class derived from a `QObject`. For my testing purposes I was looking for ways to post functions (like in io_service) to the Qt event handler (so, bypassing the `QObject::connect()` thing for simplicity), but then realized that the only posting function `QApplication::postEvent();`, takes *only Qt events* as parameters; not functions, functors or lambdas! I didn't ask about that because that's an obvious [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any major difference between QObject and io_service. As for your XY problem question, `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, []{})` accepts a lambda.